# Puppeteer page.$$ returns empty array

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm working on a simple **scraper** but I can't get past this issue.
It returns an empty array everytime I run it, however the site does contain the elements and returns a NodeList when I run *querySelectorAll* on the console.

Is there anything I migh be overlooking? I've already tried *waitForSelector* to wait for it but no luck, it just gives a timeout.

Thank you

```
const scraper = async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', "--disabled-setupid-sandbox"]});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://randomtodolistgenerator.herokuapp.com/library');
        const elements = await page.$$(".card-body");
        console.log(elements);
      
        await browser.close(); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Just because the page has loaded, doesn't mean the _content_ is there. If you `curl` that URL, you get a page back with basically nothing in it, so you'll have to make Puppeteer wait for your content to even be generated by whatever bundles `main.304f6764.chunk.js` and `1.304f6764.chunk.js` are.

Comment: The answer to "why isn't the element there" questions is always you have to wait for it or it's in a iframe.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the WSL was not able to run chromium for some reason.

I ended up installing Linux on a VM and it is working now.